# how to display in descending reverse order the cells in a 1D array inside a 2d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, reverse, display

I am doing an assignment for class and I cant figure out what I need to change and exactly where. I am starting to understand better how it all works together. However, I have tried quite a few variations that I thought might work, but they never turn out how I had intended.

The first 5 pieces of code I have gotten to work correctly through trail and error, but that 6th code/problem I can't quite figure out.

My initial code to create the 2D array is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] numbers = {{1,1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2,2},{3,3,3,3,3},{4,4,4,4,4},{5,5,5,5,5}}; 
    //made this to go around Scanner to save time/workload

    for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
        for(int columns = 0; columns < 5; columns++) {


        }
    }
```

And the code that I am having trouble with is:

```
    System.out.println("2) Your entered values are now : ");
    System.out.println( );

    for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
        for(int columns = 0; columns < rows + 1; columns++) {

            System.out.print(numbers [rows][columns]);
        }     // will replace  w/ System.out.print("*"); to get asterisks instead of numbers
        System.out.println( );
    }
    /*needs to Output *****     Outputs 1
                      ****              22
                      ***               333
                      **                4444
                      *                 55555 */
```

I have separated all 6 problems within the code and they all run off of the same input (int numbers[5][5]) and utilized similiar code. They all are displayed on a single page after each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on the way you are using for loops to print your 2d array

you are doing it in the wrong way

you can fix it by changing this condition `columns < rows + 1` to `columns < 5 - rows` at inner loop:

```
for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
      for(int columns = 0; columns < 5 - rows; columns++) {
                System.out.print(numbers [rows][columns]);
       }     // will replace  w/ System.out.print("*"); to get asterisks instead of numbers
            System.out.println( );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your rows to count from 4 to 0 instead of 0 to 4. Feel free to comment here and I'll provide additional assistance if needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Maybe_Factor

Figuring that part was easy. We had figured out what the problem was a hour after the original posting.

Here is the new code:

```
    System.out.println("6) Your entered numbers are now : ");
    System.out.println( );

    for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
        for(int columns = 0; columns < 5- rows ; columns++) {

            System.out.print("*");
```